# Certbot saves files in current directory, no private key

Tags: private-key, certbot

I have an issue where certbot (on Ubuntu) is storing the certificate files in the current directory, rather than in /etc/letsencrypt/live/${domain}. It did store files in the right place with other domain names I generated in the past, so I'm not sure what has changed.

Two important notes:

- I used a CSR file in this case, not sure if it's related
- I am generating a certificate for a url that represents a CNAME

Here's what I ran:
`certbot certonly --csr /home/me/my.csr --manual --preferred-challenges dns -d support.acme.com`

For some reason, the files are created in the directory I run the command. In addition, I do not see a private key file, only a certificate, a chain file and a full chain file, all numbered:
`0000_cert.pem,  0000_chain.pem,  0001_chain.pem`

1. Why are the files not generated under the /etc/letsencrypt/live/support.acme.com directory?
2. Why is a private key not generated?

Thanks!

Comment: (1) to write to /etc/letsencrypt you need to use sudo, but you didn't (2) a CSR is created _from_ a privatekey, so if you have a CSR you _already_ have a privatekey and don't need one created, but if one were created it wouldn't match your CSR and thus wouldn't match your cert making the whole job certbot does unusable and worthless. That's why. PS: you can't create a cert for a URL, only a domain name. A domain name can have a CNAME; a URL is not a domain name and cannot. And this is not programming or development.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks. I did run the command as root, so permissions should not have been an issue. Indeed the use of the term URL was incorrect, I should have used 'domain'. Appreciate the point about the CSR being based on a private key.  As to where I posted, I opened the question from where another certbot question was posted, sorry and thx again.

Comment: If it's not permissions and there wasn't an error mesage(s) I can't explain (1). You'll find lots of Qs (and As) for no-longer-accepted topics because until a few years ago SO accepted a much wider scope, probably because in its early years there weren't other stackexchange sites to handle other areas. But in about the last year enforcement has gotten stricter and I've seen many Qs closed for this reason. security.SX is probably best now, or maybe unix.SX.